# Bash response time is too long

Tags: bash, shell, alias

I like to have as much aliases as possible when working, so I usually maeke lots of them

There's a script (`fc.sh`) I need to execute quite often, located in `~/bin/`:

```
cd ~/42FileChecker
sh 42FileChecker.sh
```

So I made *this* alias in my `.bashrc`:

```
alias fc="sh ~/bin/fc.sh"
```

But then everytime I go in my terminal (with a `source ~/.bashrc` at launch), it takes a very long time (sometimes more than 10 or 15 seconds) to display the computer's name (the moment when I'm able to type in commands and all), so I'd have to Ctrl + C at each terminal start and after each command I use.

Does anyone knows how to solve this issue, please?

Comment: Does it take less time if you comment out that line?

Comment: You're overriding the shell's [builtin `fc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-fc)

Comment: It is unlikely, that the alias-definition can't be the reason. Maybe you changed, by mistake, something else in your .bashrc, when editing it? Put a `set -x` in the first line of your `.bashrc`, so that you can see what's going on. BTW, `fc` is a poor name for an alias, since this is also the name of a builtin command of bash.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers, it was only my alias overriding the original `fc`. It works fine now with `fch`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overriding the shell's [builtin `fc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-fc)
                    – glenn jackman